# Data extraction

Tags: jquery

since I playing around with some nodejs and express stuff I got some problems.

I got some html things available and want to extract some data to an array.
I'm able to extrac some basics things, but some more detailed data I got struggles to solve it.

Here is my html part:

```
<hr>
<h1>Topic</h1>
written by&nbsp;<font color=#ffffff>sCHween</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;am&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;at&nbsp;21:26:15
<hr>
This is my test to extract some data!
<hr>
```

and here is how I think i could

```
jsdom.env({
html: body,
scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'],
done: function(errors, window) {
var $ = window.jQuery;
$body = $(iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "ISO-8859-1")),

self.items[0] ={
  topic: $body.find('h1:eq(1)').text(),
  author: $body.find('font[color=#ffffff]').first().text(),
  date: {should be 18.06.204},
  time: {should be 21.26.15},
  text: $body.find('hr:eq(1)').nextSibling
}

console.log(self.items);
res.end('');
}
```

My questions:

I have no clue how I can get closer to the date and time?
How can I get the text out in between of the two hr tags?

For me I do not expect a finish solution - I would even more prefer if you could give me some ideas how I can achieve my targets.

Thanks a lot & have a great day
sCHween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<hr>
<h1>Topic</h1>
<b>written by&nbsp;<font color=#ffffff>sCHween</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;am&nbsp;18.06.2014&nbsp;at&nbsp;21:26:15</b>
<hr>
<i>This is my test to extract some data!</i>
<hr>
<p></p>
```

have features that are not well defined. 
must be something like my example

```
   var topic= $('h1:eq(0)').text(),
      author= $('font[color=#ffffff]').first().text(),
      text= $('i:eq(0)').text(),
      date=$('b').text().match(/(\d+)/g);
    var myArray = [ topic, author, text ];
    console.log( myArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Played around on JSFiddle and it worked. After that changed my code like this and the result is: ,9iFab,. Did I miss something important?